# Handling Timezone using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I know this question has been asked many times. I just wanted to know that how MYSQL's timestamp would handle it in my use case.

I have an application where a test paper can be assigned to multiple users(belonging to different countries). The test paper contains the start and end time. I want to know if I set the start time of a test paper to 10 am. So would it mean 10 am for each users according to their local time(different timezone applicable).

So the start time would be 10 am locally for a person living in USA, Canada etc.

How it detects the user's timezone ? From the login location of a user ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. ... By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis.

And further [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html):

> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session `time_zone` variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global `time_zone` variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am pretty confused. I though the timestamp would automatically detects the logged in user timezone and store/retrieve according to his/her time-zone.  You mentioned "client can change its own time zone". What does it mean by that ? Why the client would change the time-zone settings ? The client is not supposed to have access to the DB server.Only the DB admin have access to it. Please clarify.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know anything about your end users. It only knows who connects to it.  It sounds like you have a web server connecting to it.  The web server would be MySQL's "client".